# Use batch for multi process

Tags: sapui5

I have a customizing table that looks as follow:
[image]

As you can see on the footer, it is possible to add, delete and save items to the table.

Supposed the user add 2 new items, delete 1 item and click the save button.

My question is, how should I handle the post request to the server?

Should I send all items on the table to the server and delete all items first after insert items to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think that this will explain how to build and send batch requests. 
You should keep in mind that this snippet is made for **SAPUI5 v1.28.x**, after that batchId is *deprecated* ;)

Also you should keep in mind that I'm using **[ODataModel v2](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html)**.
These are all the methods I've used to create those calls:

- [create](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#create)
- [update](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#update)
- [remove](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#remove)

  ```
  sendBatchRequest: function (itemsToBeRemoved, itemsToBeUpdated, itemsToBeCreated) {
      var controller = this;
      var batchGroupId = "myBatchGroupId";
      var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
      var sKey = null;

      oModel.setUseBatch(true);

      //Batch request to create objects
      for( sKey in itemsToBeCreated ) {
          oModel.create(
              itemsToBeUpdated[sKey].getPath(), 
              itemsToBeUpdated[sKey].getData(), {
              batchGroupId: batchGroupId
          });
      }

      //Batch request to update objects
      //Merge will allow you to partially update object with deltas
      for( sKey in itemsToBeUpdated ) {
          oModel.update(
              itemsToBeUpdated[sKey].getPath(), 
              itemsToBeUpdated[sKey].getData(), {
              merge: true,
              batchGroupId: batchGroupId
          });
      }

      //Batch request to delete objects
      for( sKey in itemsToBeRemoved) {
          oModel.remove(itemsToBeRemoved[sKey].getPath(), {
              batchGroupId: batchGroupId
          });
      }

      oModel.setDeferredBatchGroups([batchGroupId]);
      oModel.submitChanges({
          batchGroupId: batchGroupId,
          success: function() {
              console.log("Everything is awesome!");
          },
          error: function() {
              console.log("Houston we have a problem!");
          }
      });
  }
  ```